# How to create a curved road in blender

Tags: modeling

I need to construct a track for a racing game. Can anyone suggest some good tutorials for creating a curved road.

Comment: could you please describe a little bit more? what kind of terrain? will the road follow the bumps or on contrary will it be flat? etc...

Comment: here's a tutorial I found online that might help you

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9yLVsvxpqY

Answer (score 7):

You could do it this way:

- Create your road section, subdivide it a bit:

[image]

- Create your road profile with a curve.
- In *Edit* mode, enable the normals display and make sure that the direction is correct, otherwise press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*:

[image]

- Select your road section and put it at the same point as the curve origin (select the curve, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, then select the mesh and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*):

[image]

- Give your road section an *Array* modifier, choose the amount of iterations (*Count* value), enable the *Merge* option.
- Give your road section an *Curve* modifier, choose the curve as *Object*. The object will follow along the curve. You can add a *Subdivision Surface* and click *Smooth Shadin*g to smooth it.

[image]

Now let's imagine that you want a bumpy terrain:

- Create your terrain, create your curve, subdivide your curve a bit:

[image]

- Give your curve a *Shrinkwrap* modifier so that it follows the terrain relief. Apply the modifier:

[image]

- Follow the same steps as before, create a road section and make it follow the curve:

[image]

- Once you are about glad, apply the *Array* and the *Curve* modifiers and bring some corrections manually to make a correct topology and to make it stick nicely to the terrain:

[image]

[image]

Last possibility: You need the road to be flat on a bumpy terrain. In that case you can use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier on the terrain so that it sticks to the road, then smooth its topology in *Sculpt* mode, see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199832/where-to-start-dissecting-this-racing-track/199835#199835).

Answer (score 1):

this is my way to do it this might work for you. to do this you have a add a path curve, then go to edit mode and select one of the first vertices and extrude and drag until the desired shape, then when you get to the place that its placed the first vertice that you place select it with the other and press F to joint the two curve points, then go to the curves options in properties panel, and set the fill option to front, bevel option set the value that you want, and then when you are happing with the result go to object mode and press alt+c and select mesh from curve,etc. and you are done, ofc you have to go if you want to, to edit mode to extrude, scale, or move your road as you wish. [image]