# Where to start dissecting this racing track?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I quite new to blender; i wand to make the following kind of track for a racing game i am working on. I am overwhelmed by the many things to stard; for this case is it better to start with the road or with the landscape ?

I was thinking to use spline and extrude the road to be able to adapt the road; is it the proper way of doing it ?

For the landscape i should start with a plane that i subdivide a lot but then how to get this random moving vertices ?

Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a bezier curve for the track.

1. Create the track as a bezier curve
2. Create a track segment with an *Array modifier > Fit Curve* and target the track
3. Add a *Curve modifier* to the segment and target the track

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow ! That is awesome ! How did you end up having super smooth curves like these with perfect turns ? Would you mind sharing the blend file or explain how to make it so perfect ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Hey, glad you like it :). I used grid snapping and as little control points as possible.  Added the blend.

Answer (score 6):

You terrain is quite simple, it's even low-poly style, you could do it this way:

- Create your road with the *Array* and *Curve* modifier, create a plane, subdivide it, select the parts that are supposed to be cliffs and move them up with the *Proportional Editin*g option on:

[image]

[image]

- Use the *Decimate* modifier/*Collapse* mode to create the low-poly style:

[image]

For a more highg-poly terrain, you could use the method explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJeV8djtlyU) by BlenderShortTests. Basically you need to:

- Create your terrain:

[image]

- Create your road with the *Array* + *Curve* modifier method:

[image]

- Give your terrain a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, *Wrap Method > Project, Axis > Z*, enable *Negative* and *Positive*, choose the road as *Target*:

[image]

- Apply the *Shrinwrap* modifier, sculpt the terrain in order to smooth the topology:

[image]